# Image Map within Modal

Tags: html, iframe, modal-dialog, imagemap

Not using Bootstrap, just custom classes to make the modal work. I can get the image in the modal and have added the usemap="#MapSys" which is the same in the map tag. The map tag contains the coordinates. However the image map doesn't work and the hotspot isn't active. Since it uses custom classes I can't post on jsfiddle.

```
<div id="targeted-rna-expression-div"><p><a class="modalLink[820,300]" href="/content/dam/illumina-marketing/images/applications/sequencing/amplicon-workflow-solution-lg.jpg?iframe" title="TruSeq Targeted RNA Expression Workflow" usemap="#MapSys"><span class="sequencing-rna-targeted_rna_expression"><img alt="TruSeq Targeted RNA Expression Workflow" class="roundRect left" src="/content/dam/illumina-marketing/images/applications/sequencing/amplicon-workflow-solution.jpg"></span></a><a class="modalLink[820,300]" href="/content/dam/illumina-marketing/images/applications/sequencing/amplicon-workflow-solution-lg.jpg?iframe" title="TruSeq Targeted RNA Expression Workflow" usemap="#MapSys">
  <map name="MapSys">
    <area shape="rect" coords="66,233,204,261" href="http://www.illumina.com/informatics/research/experimental-design/designstudio.html" target="_blank">
  </map>
<br>
View the workflow »</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues.  usemap is an attribute that belongs in the img tag (not in the anchor tag).  Also, make sure that there are only single instances of map name="MapSys" and usemap="#MapSys" on the page. I would put the map element right after the img tag, and no extra anchor around that map tag.

Comment: There is one img tag and that's what you click to open the modal. This isn't the image with the map so it doesn't belong there. And yes I know the use map has to be unique.

Comment: I see two instances in your example code of usemap="#MapSys" and both are in anchor tags not img.  You should include the modal popup code (and a clickable example) where the img with the usemap="#MapSys" and adjoining map name="MapSys" code should live side by side.

Comment: I moved usemap="MapSys" to the image you click to open the modal (which doesn't make sense to me the image map is on the larger image) without success. I'll ask around if I find a solution I'll let you know.

Comment: nope, move usemap="MapSys" to the image you want the map applied to.

Comment: That's how I originally had it :(